# Iteration Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

Write a function that can take any number of episode ids as input and
returns all the information about those episodes.

After taking inputs from the user as multiple id numbers, it doesn't give output as the information about all episodes

```
let BigBang =  { 
    "_embedded": {
        "episodes": [
          {
            "id": 2913,
            "name": "Pilot",
            "season": 1,
            "number": 1,
            "airdate": "2007-09-24",
            "airtime": "20:30",
            "airstamp": "2007-09-25T00:30:00+00:00",
            "runtime": 30,


            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http:\/\/api.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/2913"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2914,
            "name": "The Big Bran Hypothesis",
            "season": 1,
            "number": 2,
            "airdate": "2007-10-01",
            "airtime": "20:30",
            "airstamp": "2007-10-02T00:30:00+00:00",
            "runtime": 30,
            "image": {
              "medium": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/medium_landscape\/4\/12369.jpg",
              "original": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/original_untouched\/4\/12369.jpg"
            },
       }





    let id = prompt('Enter the episode ids');
   let Info = (...id) => {
       for(let current in BigBang._embedded.episodes) {
           if(BigBang._embedded.episodes[current].id === parseInt(id)) {
               let Detail = BigBang._embedded.episodes[current];
               console.log(Detail);
           }
       }
   }
   Info(id);
```

Comment: You are pretty much missing all close symbols on BigBang ]}}

Comment: You're using `parseInt` on an array.

Comment: Why `(...id)`? `prompt` returns a string.

Comment: @JaredSmith while that is true, parseInt([3]) = parseInt([3].toString()) = parseInt("3") = 3

Comment: @juvian But only for a single number: _"After taking inputs from the user as **multiple id numbers**"_.

Comment: @Andreas true ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After taking inputs from the user as multiple id numbers, it doesn't give output as the information about all episodes

Assuming you need to pass multiple ids, you can use the function `filter` along with the function `indexOf` **(This is to convert to number and compare, of course, you can map that array first, Etc,. But that part is up to you).**

This example receives the ids separated by comma and call the function `Info`using the function `apply` to pass the entered ids as parameters **(Like I said this is an example, in real execution you will pass the parameters directly to the function `Info`)**.

```js
let BigBang = {  "_embedded": {    "episodes": [{        "id": 2913,        "name": "Pilot",        "season": 1,        "number": 1,        "airdate": "2007-09-24",        "airtime": "20:30",        "airstamp": "2007-09-25T00:30:00+00:00",        "runtime": 30,        "_links": {          "self": {            "href": "http:\/\/api.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/2913"          }        }      },      {        "id": 2914,        "name": "The Big Bran Hypothesis",        "season": 1,        "number": 2,        "airdate": "2007-10-01",        "airtime": "20:30",        "airstamp": "2007-10-02T00:30:00+00:00",        "runtime": 30,        "image": {          "medium": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/medium_landscape\/4\/12369.jpg",          "original": "http:\/\/static.tvmaze.com\/uploads\/images\/original_untouched\/4\/12369.jpg"        },      }    ]  }};

let id = prompt('Enter the episode ids (separated by comma)');
let Info = (...ids) => {
  var episodes = BigBang._embedded.episodes.filter(e => ids.findIndex(i => e.id == +i) !== -1);
  console.log(episodes);
}

Info.apply(null, id.split(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: _"along with `indexOf`"_ but you're using `.findIndex()` (and why not `.includes()` if you're already using the new "fancy" stuff?).

Comment: @Andreas what's unclear? I mentioned the necessary to understand!

Comment: I've missed the `.apply()` (removed that part from my comment above). But that is, imho, overly complicated. Just call `Info(id.split(","))` and use `ids` directly without the spread syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = prompt('Enter the episode ids');
let idArray = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");
let Info = (ids) => BigBang._embedded.episodes.filter(b => ids.includes(b.id));
console.log(Info(idArray));
```